# Dropdowns not working (Twitter bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hello I just want to ask where I am wrong. I have button with dropdown using twitter bootstrap but I cant work it out. please see my codes. Im just new in twitter bootstrap. I also try searching it on bootstrap site but I cant work it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js/bootstrap-min.js"></script>

    <link href="../../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown">
        <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn" href="#">Dropdown menu here...
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="/app/1">Item A</a></li>
              <li><a href="/app/2">Item B</a></li>
              <li><a href="/app/3">Item C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code. Please look at the Bootstrap docs to see how to implement a dropdown. You're also loading two Bootstrap CSS files when you only need the minified one. Additionally you're loading an old version of jQuery. Also you're loading dropdown.js when you really only need the minified Bootstrap JS. Lastly your HTML is malformed. The only valid child of a UL is an LI. I'll assume you're using the latest build of Bootstrap? Here's the link to the docs for the dropdowns: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: Cool, I'll add my reply as an answer and you can accept when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is no need to add dropdown.js because u already added bootstap.min.js

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn" href="#">Dropdown menu here...
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/app/1">Item A</a></li>
          <li><a href="/app/2">Item B</a></li>
          <li><a href="/app/3">Item C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js/bootstrap-min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bS78M/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with your code. Please look at the Bootstrap docs to see how to implement a dropdown. You're also loading two Bootstrap CSS files when you only need the minified one. Additionally you're loading an old version of jQuery. Also you're loading dropdown.js when you really only need the minified Bootstrap JS. Lastly your HTML is malformed. The only valid child of a UL is an LI. I'll assume you're using the latest build of Bootstrap? Here's the link to the docs for the dropdowns: getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns –